# Why can I not use the Django server for production?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django for the first time and I'm also relatively new to Python. On the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/), it says,

> "You’ve started the Django development server, a lightweight Web
>   server written purely in Python. [...] don’t use this server in
>   anything resembling a production environment. It’s intended only for
>   use while developing."

Why shouldn't I use the Django server for production? Why do I need a separate server? I'm from a Node/Express background, and when I created an Express application, I could just deploy it to Heroku without doing too much. How will this be different for Django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Django's built in web server in a production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867793/using-djangos-built-in-web-server-in-a-production-environment)

Comment: It's not different. You can indeed "just deploy to Heroku without doing too much". You just don't use the development server for that.

Comment: Express apps use Node's api and server behind the scenes to serve connections, hence it's already production ready. Whereas the built-in Django server is created just for the sake of development, with no emphasis on security or efficient threading etc.

Answer (score -3):

Because of security and performance reasons. It's only meant to be used while developing.

Comment: Please add more information on what those security and performance reasons are. Thanks!